# Каким образом реализовать двусвязный список, чтобы избежать ошибки с функцией поиск элемента?

Tags: c, list, указатели

Работаю в Visual Studio 2022.
Задача состоит в том, что необходимо считать строки из файла в список, одновременно с этим сортируя их по длинам в определенном порядке. Пользователь может ввести любое число и получить все строки этого размера. Изначальное решение заключалось в создании односвязного списка, я же решил немного его поменять и создать двусвязный список, а поиск элемента вести в обратном порядке через указатели на предыдущий элемент списка.
При запусках с одинаковым кодом эти элементы то выводятся без ошибок, то выводятся с кодом -1073741819, то вовсе не выводятся, то выводятся не в полном количестве с тем же кодом.
В ходе отладки обнаружил, что иногда нулевой указатель q не воспринимается компилятором как нулевой.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma warning(disable:4996)

struct List
{
    int length;
    char* word;
    struct List* next;
    struct List* prev;
};
static struct List* Last;
void printList(struct List* s)
{
    putchar('\n');
    while (s != Last)
    {
        printf("%s %d \n", s->word,s->length);
        s = s->next;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
void printTen(struct List* s)
{
    putchar('\n');
    for (int i = 1; i < 4 ; i++)
    {
        printf("%d %s\n",i, s->word);
        s = s->next;
    }
}

struct List* InitList(void)
{
    struct List* s;
    Last = s = (struct List*)malloc(sizeof(Last));
    s->next = NULL;
    s->prev = NULL;
    return s;
}

struct List* Add2List(struct List* s, char* word, int length)
{
    struct List* q = s;
    while (!((q->length - length) > 0 && ((q->next == Last)?1:(q->next)->length - length <= 0)) && q->next)
        q = q->next;
    if (q != Last)
    {
        struct List* p = (struct List*)malloc(sizeof(Last));
        p->length = length;
        p->word = word;
        p->next = q->next;
        q->next->prev = p;
        q->next = p;
        p->prev = q;
    }
    else
    {
        q = (struct List*)malloc(sizeof(Last));
        q->length = length;
        q->word = word;
        q->next = s;
        s->prev = q;
        s = q;
        q->prev = NULL;
        if ((q->next)?q->next->prev:0)
            q->next->prev = q;
    }
    return s;
}

void PrintByNum(struct List* s,int num)
{
    struct List* q = Last->prev;
    int IsHere = 0;
    putchar('\n');
    while (q)
    {
        if (q->length == num)
        {
            printf("%s\n", q->word);
            IsHere = 1;
        }
        q = q->prev;
    }
    if (!IsHere)
        printf("There are no strings with given length!");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct List* s = InitList();
    FILE* f;
    if ((f = fopen("words.txt", "r")) == NULL)
        printf("File wasn't opened");
    char* word;
    int length;

    char buf[20];
    fscanf(f, "%s", buf);
    
    while (!feof(f))
    {
        word = (char*)malloc(strlen(buf) + 1);
        strcpy(word, buf);
        length = strlen(word);

        s = Add2List(s, word, length);

        fscanf(f, "%s", buf);
        
    }
    printTen(s);

    PrintByNum(s, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Использование связного списка требуется по условию?

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(Last))` возвращает память размера указателя. Используйте размер структуры : `malloc(sizeof(struct List))`

Comment: .. или `malloc(sizeof ( * Last))`

Comment: Да, связный список требовался по условию. Большое спасибо AlexGlebe, Ваша поправка решила проблему!!